# In CodeIgniter, is there a performance disadvantage to loading unecessary libraries, helpers etc?

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter

In creating a log in process in CodeIgniter I have this for the __construct.

```
 public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('session');
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->helper('url');
      $this->load->helper('html');
      $this->load->database();
      $this->load->library('form_validation');

      $this->load->model('login_model');
 }
```

The index method contains all the necessary code to handle the login.

I am going to set up the log out process and decided instead of creating another controller for the log out I would create a method in the login controller that handles the log out and call it directly.

Obviously the __construct will run when calling the log out method but should I place an if statement in the __construct for items that will not be needed for the log out?  For instance not loading the login_model.

This question is not specific to this instance but for overall performance in all the other controllers that I may create and reuse to consolidate code. I am not thinking only about speed but system resources with heavy volume.

Comment: You can measure benefits with [Benchmarking Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, there is a performance hit for loading anything, so if you don't need it, don't load it.

The longer answer is that you are unlikely to get enough traffic that this is going to be a major factor in the development of the site, but there are other good reasons to not load unnecessary libraries - mainly, to reduce clutter and confusion. When you come back to this function in three months and see what's being loaded, are you going to remember which libraries are needed and which are there "just in case," or will you wind up spending half an hour tracing out the dependencies? At this point you should prioritize ease of development over performance.

In either case, though, don't load libraries that you don't need.

Comment: I agree with this.  My development experience is in ColdFusion and I am new to CodeIgniter.  I wanted to see how others have found the performance of CodeIgniter to be and how far to go in eliminating unnecessary loading.  I always try to load only the absolute necessary so adding new and refactoring old is easier and more pleasant.

Comment: Ah, OK. To just elaborate a little more, imho CodeIgniter is fine for simple or toy projects but I don't think it's considered a serious solution for complex projects or those with strong performance requirements. It's also a bear for unit testing because of its reliance on the superobject pattern.